# osgART install on windows - CMake error 'Could NOT find OpenSceneGraph'

Tags: c++, augmented-reality, openscenegraph

CMake error occurs for building osgART. I'm following the procedure mentioned in the website of osgART. I have built OpenSceneGraph-3.2.0 successfully. The ENVR. variables for osg are

```
OSG_ROOT=E:\Dev\OpenSceneGraph-3.2.0
OSG_BIN= %OSG_ROOT%\build_VS2008\bin
OSG_INCLUDE_PATH = %OSG_ROOT%\include
OSG_LIB_PATH = %OSG_ROOT%\build_VS2008\lib
PATH=%OSG_BIN%
```

CMake error for osgART

```
Could NOT find OpenSceneGraph: Found unsuitable version "..", but required
is at least "3.2.0"
```

CMake is able to find all the required libs of osg.
osgART is also in E:\Dev. I have tried with other versions of osg also like 3.0.1 and 3.3.0 developer version, but still facing the same errors. ARToolKit is also installed in the same directory. Moreover the plugins options for osgART in CMake as shown in the install procedure in the osgART website, is also not appearing. Only osg inlcude and libs path appears in CMake.

What steps am I  missing?

Regards,

Andres.

Answer (score 0):

I would start hunting on this error : Found unsuitable version "..",

It looks that the *Config.cmake has not been imported

May those links help :

http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/How_to_create_a_ProjectConfig.cmake_file#The_FooBar.2FFooBarConfig.cmake.in_file

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/ctest2.6docs.html#command:find_package